# HBase row key design: hotspotting vs. locality of reference

Tags: key, hbase, localityofreference

Consider a hypothetical HBase table.

- The key must encode a 3-tuple `(k, m, n)` of integers between 0 and 1000.
- The typical read is a range query over `m` and `n`, fixing a value of `k`.
- The read load is [exponentially distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) with respect to `k`. In other words, a few values of `k` are responsible for most of the read load.

Alice argues that the key should look like `"k-m-n"` in order to exploit locality of reference. Ideally, a single machine should be able to serve an entire query.

Bob argues that the key should look like `"sha1(k-m)-n"` in order to avoid [hotspotting](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/hbase-0.98.6-cdh5.3.8/book/rowkey.design.html): if `k=1` is accessed extremely often, then it would be wise for all the `k=1` records to **not** all be on the same few machines.

Both arguments make sense to me. How do I figure out which option is more scalable/future-proof? Is there a quick, practical way to test this empirically?

Comment: That is patter of read is sequence read, reading in several threads, by map reduce or spark job?

Comment: I *think* it's going to be mostly Spark jobs, but ideally whatever solution we pick shouldn't lock us into a particular processing framework.